# Practical advantage of providing a block to 'Array#fill'

Tags: arrays, ruby

The [`Array#fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) method is capable with both objects and blocks. Why was it designed to work with blocks as well, where the absolute index is passed? What is the benefit from practical perspective?

Comment: The documentation contains this one: `a.fill { |i| i*i }` – how would you fill `a` with square numbers without using the block form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two reasons. The first, as shown in the documentation you linked, is when you need to fill the array with *different values*:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.fill { |i| i*i }  #=> [0, 1, 4, 9]
```

The other, less obvious, reason is when you need to fill the array with *different objects* (even of the same value). Consider the following:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.fill("x")  #=> ["x", "x", "x", "x"]

# BUT, these are actually the same object in memory:
a.map(&:object_id)
# => [70193065904260, 70193065904260, 70193065904260, 70193065904260]

# This means mutating one element will mutate all elements:
b = a.first
b << " CHANGED"
a  #=> ["x CHANGED", "x CHANGED", "x CHANGED", "x CHANGED"]
```

By contrast, using the block form will allow you to create new objects each time:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.fill{ "x" }  #=> ["x", "x", "x", "x"]

# These are now DIFFERENT objects in memory:
a.map(&:object_id)
# => [70193070608480, 70193070608460, 70193070608400, 70193070608340]

# This means mutating one element will not affect the others:
b = a.first
b << " CHANGED"
a  #=> ["x CHANGED", "x", "x", "x"]
```

This principle is a [common gotcha](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) when dealing with Arrays in ruby, although it applies more often to constructing new arrays rather than filling existing ones.